# give more score to specific document in elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

consider I have this full text query :

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "blue"
    }
  }
}
```

and I got this result :

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 4,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 0.32156613,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_id": "rQ5WIYYBUZECFnMRbIo6",
        "_score": 0.32156613,
        "_source": {
          "title": "blue chair blue desk"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_id": "qg5VIYYBUZECFnMRrorJ",
        "_score": 0.29879427,
        "_source": {
          "title": "blue bird"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_id": "qw5VIYYBUZECFnMR8IpD",
        "_score": 0.29879427,
        "_source": {
          "title": "blue sky"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_id": "rg5WIYYBUZECFnMRsoqo",
        "_score": 0.29879427,
        "_source": {
          "title": "blue automobile"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

you see scoring is completely working fine, but I want to specifically give more score to the document with **title:"blue sky"** whenever the search is blue so it would be my top result.
Is there any way to specifically increase the score of some documents while querying in Elasticsearch ?

I think it could be done by combining match and positive boost query but and I couldn't do that

Answer (score 0):

An option is using boosting query. You can decrease the scoring document that you do not want.
I applied a negative boost to documents without the term sky in the example.

```
{
  "query": {
    "boosting": {
      "positive": {
        "match": {
          "title": "blue"
        }
      },
      "negative": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "match": {
                "title": "sky"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "negative_boost": 0.1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you. but consider that it is not only this query I want to run . for example in case of searching "yellow" I want yellow sun to be scored more. I think it is kind of related to giving more score to specifically important documents while indexing

Comment: so you need to add a weight to the documents, that way you can apply a query function and through the weight of each document you can change the score.